# In docker composer container raise error : Carbon 1 is deprecated

Tags: docker, laravel-5, php-carbon

I tried to run under docker my laravel 5.5 / postgres 9 app and in composer container I got error :

> Carbon 1 is deprecated, see how to migrate to Carbon 2.
>   https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-carbon-2
>       You can run './vendor/bin/upgrade-carbon' to get help in updating carbon and other frameworks and libraries that depend on it.

My composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.3",
        "graham-campbell/markdown": "^8.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "khill/lavacharts": "3.0.*",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/socialite": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.0",
        "nwidart/laravel-modules": "^2.2",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.5",
        "wboyz/laravel-enum": "^0.2.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
        "stolz/laravel-html-tidy": "^0.1.1",
        "xethron/migrations-generator": "^2.0",
        "filp/whoops" : "~2.0" 
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Modules\\": "Modules/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],

        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]

    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3'

services:

    web:
        build:
            context: ./web           # directory of web/Dockerfile.yml
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.yml

        environment:
            - APACHE_RUN_USER=#1000

        container_name: lprods_web

        volumes:
            - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        ports:
            - 8086:80
        working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}



    db:
        image: postgres:9.6.10-alpine
        container_name: lprods_db
        ports:
            - '5433:5432'
        restart: always
        environment: 
            POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '1'
            POSTGRES_DB: 'wprods'
        volumes:
            - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/


    adminer:
        image: adminer
        container_name: lprods_adminer
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8087:80
        links:
            - db

    composer:
        image: composer:1.6
        container_name: lprods_composer
        volumes:
            - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        command: composer install  --ignore-platform-reqs
```

and web/Dockerfile.yml :

```
  FROM php:7.1-apache

    RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    python \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    nano \
    git-core \
    curl \
    build-essential \
    openssl \
    libssl-dev \
    libgmp-dev \
    libldap2-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    netcat \
    sqlite3 \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    && git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git \
    && cd node \
    && git checkout v12.0.0 \
    && ./configure \
    && make \
    && make install

    RUN npm install cross-env

    RUN  docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-webp-dir=/usr/include/  --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/


    RUN  docker-php-ext-install gd pgsql pdo_pgsql zip gmp bcmath pcntl ldap sysvmsg exif \
    && a2enmod rewrite

    COPY virtualhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

I am not sure which steps have I to take?
To add command

```
RUN ./vendor/bin/upgrade-carbon
```

In the end of web/Dockerfile.yml file ?

**MODIFIED :**
Entering the docker bash I tried to run proposed command, but got error :

```
$ docker-compose exec web bash
root@863c9aa86d25:/var/www/lprods_docker_root# php -v
PHP 7.1.33 (cli) (built: Oct 25 2019 06:33:10) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
root@863c9aa86d25:/var/www/lprods_docker_root# ./vendor/bin/upgrade-carbon
sh: 1: composer: not found

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Composer\Composer' not found in /var/www/lprods_docker_root/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Upgrade.php:131
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/lprods_docker_root/vendor/nesbot/carbon/bin/upgrade-carbon(28): Carbon\Upgrade::upgrade()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/lprods_docker_root/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Upgrade.php on line 131
```

?

**MODIFIED # 2:** 
I tried to add proposed upgrade-carbon command into web/Dockerfile.yml file :

```
RUN  docker-php-ext-install gd pgsql pdo_pgsql zip gmp bcmath pcntl ldap sysvmsg exif \
&& a2enmod rewrite

RUN ./vendor/bin/upgrade-carbon

COPY virtualhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

But I got error :

```
Step 5/7 : RUN  docker-php-ext-install gd pgsql pdo_pgsql zip gmp bcmath pcntl ldap sysvmsg exif     && a2enmod rewrite
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 60c29909c34a
Step 6/7 : RUN ./vendor/bin/upgrade-carbon
 ---> Running in 4fb9274ac5cb
/bin/sh: 1: ./vendor/bin/upgrade-carbon: not found
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c ./vendor/bin/upgrade-carbon' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

I suppose I need to run upgrade-carbon command AFTER command in composer file:

```
command: composer install  --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Can I do this in docker and how?

Thanks!

Comment: Pls, look MODIFIED.

Comment: Pls, look MODIFIED 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a decision with line added to composer.json:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "nesbot/carbon": "2 as 1.24.1"
},
```

and that works for me!